# How to detect that import('/some-url') failed because '/some-url' isn't a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, es6-modules, dynamic-import

My browser-side JavaScript uses a dynamic import `import('/some-url')` which sometimes throws an error.

How can I tell whether the thrown error originates from the loaded JavaScript module, or from the browser because no JavaScript module was found at `'/some-url'`?

The error thrown by the browser if `'/some-url'` doesn't return a JavaScript module doesn't seem to follow any convention:

- In Chrome, `err.message` is `'Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://stackoverflow.com/some-url'`
- In firefox, `err.message` is `'error loading dynamically imported module'`.

A hackish way to implement this:

```js
async function isJavaScriptModule(url) {
  try {
    await import(url);
  } catch (err) {
    if (isNetworkError(err)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      // The module at `url` may throw an error when loaded.
      // It's still a JavaScript module so we return true.
      return true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function isNetworkError(err) {
  const messages = [
    "Failed to fetch dynamically imported module",
    "error loading dynamically imported module",
  ];
  return messages.some((msg) => err.message.includes(msg));
}
```

But that isn't reliable, since browser vendors may change the error message at any time.

Is there a more reliable way to implement this?

Comment: It'll probably be pretty complicated to distinguish the module not being evaluated due to a loading or syntax error from the module being evaluated and `throw`ing an identical error itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed no easy way to determine this. The script execution could throw the exact same error you'd get with a network error and you'd have no way of knowing where it came from.

```js
import(`data:text/javascript,
  throw new TypeError("I can pretend I'm an import error");
`).catch((err) => 
    console.log(`[${ Object.getPrototypeOf(err).name }]`, err.message)
  );
```

So for this you will probably have to fetch again the resource on your own, and perform the same checks that `import()` does.

You'll first want to ensure that you're allowed to fetch and that the URL is a valid URL. This is handled by the call to `fetch(url)`. If it throws here, your script didn't execute.
Then you will have to check if the `Response` instance's `.ok` is true, otherwise the browser will fail to import the module script.
Finally, you'll want to ensure the `Content-Type` of the resource is correctly set to one of [the many JS MIME types](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-mime-type) (assuming you're loading a JS module).

This last step is probably the most complicated since this "Content-Type" header can come in many forms. I'll provide a really quickly made sketch below, but you should really search for a better one (e.g [jsdom has one](https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-mimetype)).

```js
const urls = [
  // expected ok
  ["https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js", true],
  // expected ok, even if the module throws (yes, there is a "throw" pkg, and yes it throws as ESM ;)
  ["https://unpkg.com/throw", true],
  // expected not-ok (404)
  ["https://unpkg.com/notok", false],
  // expected Network Error
  ["https://v8.dev/_js/main.mjs", false],
];

const isValidJSModule = async (url) => {
  try {
    // We use `mode: "cors"` to perform the same request as `import()`
    // and `method: "HEAD" to avoid fetching the whole resource again
    resp = await fetch(url, { mode: "cors", method: "HEAD" });
    return resp.ok && isJSMIME(resp.headers.get("content-type"));
  }
  catch(err) {
    return false; // or "Network Error" if you prefer
  }
}

const tryToImport = async (url) => {
  try {
    return await import(url);
  }
  catch(err) {
    return "Failed to import";
  }
}

const test = async ([url, expected]) => {
  const module = await tryToImport(url);
  // You'd perform it only in case import() failed
  const isValid = await isValidJSModule(url);
  console.log({ url, module, isValid, expected });
}
urls.forEach(test);

function isJSMIME(fullType) {
  // this is naive and may very well fail
  const type = fullType.split(";")[0].toLowerCase().trim();
  return [
    "application/ecmascript",
    "application/javascript",
    "application/x-ecmascript",
    "application/x-javascript",
    "text/ecmascript",
    "text/javascript",
    "text/javascript1.0",
    "text/javascript1.1",
    "text/javascript1.2",
    "text/javascript1.3",
    "text/javascript1.4",
    "text/javascript1.5",
    "text/jscript",
    "text/livescript",
    "text/x-ecmascript",
    "text/x-javascript",
  ].includes(type);
}
```

Ps: Note that in Firefox it seems the returned error's `.stack` is the empty string when it's caused by a network error, while it points to the faulty script otherwise. Unfortunately at least Chrome doesn't do the same and I'm not sure any behavior is specced.

Answer (score 0):

Id try fetching, then checking if the fetch worked and returned a js module and then importing:

```js
async function isJavaScriptModule(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (response.headers.get("content-type") === "application/javascript") {
      await import(url);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many JS MIMEs, (the "official" one for HTML being "text/javascript" btw), and they can all have headers appended to them (e.g `, charset="utf8"`). So your test should account for these or you'll reject a lot of valid responses. Also, this doesn't really tell apart "network" errors from script errors (e.g the script throws at execution), which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: Wouldn't this load every file twice, one time for checking the headers and one more time for the actual import?